# Salvage Hebrew from MySQL column with wrong character set

Tags: php, mysql, character

So stupidly I've stored hebrew in a MySQL table with the wrong character set. I realised after an influx of data was entered and I'm wondering if it's still possible to access that data. I've since changed the character set of the table to hebrew using CONVERT TO and new entries store correctly, but old entries are still appearing as:

```
×?×? ×× ×? ×?×?×?×¨ ×?×?×©×?×§ ×?××? ×?×?×©×?×§
```

Is there anyway to modify that data back to hebrew or has the damage been done?

Comment: looks like it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, it looks like the x-like character is the escape for the Hebrew plane.

Look into `http://php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-decode.php`.

If utf8-decode doesn't work, one of the functions in the comments might do. Be sure to use a multibyte character set for PHP.